# Best image cache for loading numerous images in UITableView for IOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9, image-caching

Could any one please tell me the best image cache available for loading numerous images in UITableviewcell?

Currently i am using **SDWebimageCache** but it seems it is creating problems in IOS9 particularly in iPad where the table scrolling makes the app to crash.

**Help me with SDWebimagecache alternative.**

The class which i used from SDWebImageCache is:

```
[cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:imageLoadUrl
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"*placeholder image*"]
                             options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

The class which i used from UIIMageView + AFNetworking is:

```
[cell.imgMain setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"]
                          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                              cell.imgMain.image=image;
                          }
                          failure:nil];
```

But still the application crashes and shows the following screen:

APPLICATION CRASHES IN IOS 9 and sometimes for IOS 8.4

Please help me from this situation. Lots of pressure ...

[image]

Comment: That isn't so much as a crash, rather an Xcode bug / issue where it looses connection to the device as it states. Try running the app in the simulator if you're having device issues.

Comment: I first thought that .. But i am 100 percent sure that it is not the case.. The app crashes still when i disconnect the cable.

Comment: Go into Xcode, and then into the breakpoint navigator (cmd + 7) and add an all exception breakpoint. And run the app again to see where it crashes. Right now; there is not enough information to help with anything. You need to isolate the offending code that causes the issue.

Comment: [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:imageLoadUrl
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"*placeholder image*"]
                             options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

Comment: if i comment this it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking) has a great `UIImage category` that does this well and works on `iOS9`. I too had issues with `SDWebimageCache` on `iOS9`.

Comment: Thanks Dude !! Could you please refer me with another image cache category class??

Comment: What's wrong with AFNetworking that doesn't suit your needs? I use AFN in my project for network calls as well as image loading. Have done for the last two years and its a very solid library

Comment: Okk...Could you please provide me with image cache tutorial using AFnetworking please??

Comment: The problem is not your library you are using; it will be your code. To have two different libraries crashing suggests an issue in your code. Update your question with the relevant code and exact crash log that shows in the console

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

> AsyncImageView includes both a simple category on UIImageView for loading and displaying images asynchronously on iOS so that they do not lock up the UI, and a UIImageView subclass for more advanced features. AsyncImageView works with URLs so it can be used with either local or remote files.
>
> Loaded/downloaded images are cached in memory and are automatically cleaned up in the event of a memory warning. The AsyncImageView operates independently of the UIImage cache, but by default any images located in the root of the application bundle will be stored in the UIImage cache instead, avoiding any duplication of cached images.
>
> The library can also be used to load and cache images independently of a UIImageView as it provides direct access to the underlying loading and caching classes

Comment: Sorry still the UITableView crashes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JMImageCache` For lazy loading of image in UITableView